# What is the form of a PrimalityProving`PrimeQCertificate?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I understand the format of a proof of compositeness of an integer produced by `PrimeQCertificate`: it's well-documented that `PrimeQCertificate[a]` outputs one of:

- a triple `{a, n-1, n}` such that $a^{n-1} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ (that is, Fermat's test proves compositeness), or
- a triple `{a, 2, n}` such that $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $a \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{n}$ (which is a test derived from considering a difference of two squares).

For primality rather than compositeness, the documentation says it "uses the Pratt certificate and the Atkin-Morain certificate for primality."

What do these look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Pratt test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate#Pratt_certificates) of `n` produces *either* the integer $2$, *or* a tuple `{n, a, {certs}}`
where each `cert` is another certificate of primality, and such that

- $(a, n) = 1$
- $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$
- `certs` is a list of certificates for the primality of each prime $q \mid n-1$
- $a^{(n-1)/q} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ for all $q \mid n-1$

These conditions together force $n$ to satisfy the Lucas test for primality.

I have never seen an Atkin-Morain certificate generated.